# How was Rose able to project herself onto the TARDIS screen and onto the screen in Midnight?

Tags: doctor-who

Rose Tyler appears on two different screens in series four of *Doctor Who*, before making her official return.

[image: Rose screen 1]

[image: Rose screen 2]

My question is, how? It's never explained in the actual show. Is it ever explained in any of the expanded universe works or by Word of God?

Comment: "Because Bad Wolf" isn't a sufficient answer, is it?

Comment: @gowenfawr Didn't the 9th Doctor kiss that out of her?

Comment: I thought "Once a Bad Wolf, always a Bad Wolf" was truer than most once you've looked into the Heart of the Tardis...

Comment: Alternate Universe Torchwood, one assumes.

Comment: A big ball of wibbly-wobbly hand-wavy stuff?

Answer (score 8):

With the help of an alternate-universe UNIT and the dying remnant of the Doctor's Tardis.

In "Midnight", we see Rose attempting to contact the Doctor and failing.   In "Turn Left", she attempts to contact Donna and succeeds.   In the scene that reveals the mystery peeking over Donna's shoulder, we also see that UNIT jury-rigged this Tardis in order to make contact and travel between universes possible.

What we see in "Midnight" makes sense if we assume that she's using the jury-rigged Tardis and the resulting portal between universes to connect with our Doctor's Tardis.   It's a ship-to-ship communications link between two points in history of what could be the same ship, leaping through something like a wormhole bridge generated between otherwise parallel and separate universes.

This explanation doesn't reference the expanded universe continuity.   It's simply something that makes sense when referencing nothing more than the on-screen continuity.   We get enough explanation for the "Midnight" cameo during "Turn Left" that I wouldn't bother looking anywhere else.

Comment: I don't know; if the Pete's Universe Torchwood was capable of inter-dimensional travel on their own, do we really need another entity to explain inter-dimensional broadcasting?

Comment: Yes, but Pete's World UNIT were visibly present and saluting.  Torchwood didn't seem involved.  Maybe Rose could have used the Rift, but what she was shown to use was the (or maybe *a*) Tardis.

Comment: Turn Left doesn't take place in Pete's Universe; it is an alternate timeline in The Doctor's Universe - call it The Late Doctor's Universe. Specific mention is made of The Royal Family being wiped out in the destruction of London. I don't know that there is any evidence of Pete's Universe having UNIT, or its own Doctor and TARDIS for that matter.

Comment: Most of "Turn Left" occurs in, oh, let's call it Bug's World.  Rose travels from Pete's World to Bug's World in order to meet Donna.  If this is the Rose that was stuck in Pete's World, then it's Pete's UNIT that sends her to Donna.  We see this UNIT on-screen -- several soldiers and a ranking officer.  I call that strong evidence.

Comment: Why would that be Pete's World UNIT? Why wouldn't Bug's World UNIT have recovered The TARDIS after The Doctor's death?

Comment: It's not a detail that I remember, but, wikipedia indicates that the Bug's World Torchwood team died during the Sontaran invasion.  Anyway, unless you're claiming that Rose wasn't on Pete's World, then obviously Rose's UNIT is Pete's World UNIT.  If it had been the Bug's World UNIT that recovered a TARDIS, then we would never have seen Rose.  Rose travels ***to*** Bug's World, not ***from*** it.